# getActiveUser() doesn't return the user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I've just published my addon to G Suite Marketplace for the first time :D

(After about 2 weeks, Google had published our addon today)

And the first thing that I noticed is: **A lot of bugs** :(

Although I had tested my code with my bound document very carefully.

**Those bugs related to this line of code:**

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
```

It always returns an empty string, though I had OAuth permission for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

I guess (but can't be sure) that I need to use this function instead:

```
Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
```

I can't be sure because I had updated the code and submitted a new version to  G Suite Marketplace but Google didn't publish it yet (maybe because the migration from Addon Store to G Suite Marketplace is still unstable)

So do you have experience with Addon on G Suite Marketplace about this problem?

Should I use `getEffectiveUser()` instead of `getActiveUser()` all the time ?

---

**EDIT:**

This is the context of the code that runs Session.getActiveUser():

- After the user has accepted the OAuth permissions
- The sidebar appeared
- The client-side code call functionX (that has a call to Session.getActveUser()) using `google.script.run.functionX...`

> According to this guide
>   https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes,
>   when using google.script.run, the AuthMode is FULL

Comment: As [the documentation indicates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()), it's highly context dependent. Can you provide details about the context in which that code is executing? For reference, see the [Authorization Modes documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes). If the code is being executed in a context where the authorization mode is anything other than `AuthMode.FULL`, that explains the empty string being returned.

Comment: @chuckx: Thanks. I edited my question to provide the information about context

Comment: Questions that look for help debugging code should include a [mcve] (in this case include server side and client side code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can read on the [`getActiveUser()` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()), you will get a blank string if you can't access the user information. Since the `AuthMode` can change automatically in some situations (as detailed on the [authorization modes documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes)), we advise to log it to check if it is on `AuthMode.FULL` or any other mode. We hope that this is useful for you. Please, don't hesitate to offer us more information for further help.